# How to create an icon dinamically by its name?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm generating menu dynamically and icon name is one of the configuration possible: but how can I call the icon dynamically without explicitly importing it?

```
let { name, icon } = menuEntry;
<ListItem primaryText={name} leftIcon={what here?} />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In one of my projects I have the following:

```
import * as Icons from 'material-ui/svg-icons';
```

and then I can use any icon I want it like this:

```
let Icon = Icons[iconName];
return (
  <Icon />
);
```

`iconName` needs to be a valid icon name.
In your example it would look like this:

```
let { name, icon } = menuEntry;
<ListItem primaryText={name} leftIcon={Icons[icon]} />
```

Comment: will this solution break tree shaking? Thanks! :)

Comment: I guess so, in this case, I'm importing all icons and as long as you have a reference to your import tree shaking will not be applied ( all the icons will be included in final bundle )

Comment: doh! then it's a no-go... since svg icons are ~4mb :(